# HCI Script for BLE-ADV

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

I'm trying to perform BLE Advertisement through TI-LAUNCHXL-CC2640R2 using HCI Scripts.I've written the HCI Script ON HCI Tester for this purpose but can't get my device discovered using nRF Connect app on Phone.

Is there any hardware config.on the chip that I am missing as I only have connected my development kit with PC using USB.

What could be the reason and solution for this problem?[HCI-Script for Advertisement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlBfq.png)

I tried changing some parameters like configuring the Adv Type to Scannable and providing all the three adv channels but still the device is not getting discovered (Advertisement failed). What can I do to resolve this?